# Is there a way to programmatically access Google's search engine results?

Tags: api, google-search, pagerank, google-search-api

Does google offer a way to programmatically see their search engine results for a certain query?

I want to build a tracking application so that a user can see what rank on the google results their website is for certain keywords.

EDIT: The behavior of the program would be: every day the program queries Google for the desired phrases, sees what position the user's websites are, and emails the users an update of their positions for their phrases.

I want to be sure to comply with Google's terms of service too.

Comment: One of the best solution is to use a third party API like [SerpApi](https://serpapi.com).

Comment: Aug 2023 - there is no official API. There are 3rd party scrapers that provide this API, some are mentioned in this thread

Answer (score 24):

After finding this question I have been researching as the other answers seem out of date.

The Google search API would be the obvious choice as quoted by other users however it is [now been deprecated](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/103123/what-ever-happened-to-the-google-ajax-search-api) in favour of Custom Search API.

Although not obvious at first the [Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/) does allow you to search the entire web. However the bad news is that the order of the [results are not the same as a regular web search](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/customsearch/thread?tid=56c0bd92dda351b7&hl=en).

In conclusion it used to be possible however it is no longer. The new API (at a cost) will allow you to search the web to you will not be able to get the ranking back as required.

Comment: Yeah, a ridiculously high cost too - $5 per 1000 searches.

Comment: How does it allow me to search entire web? I have to limit it to a domain or  Schema.org Types.

Answer (score 14):

I know the question is Google specific, but it doesn't hurt to try out other search engines which might be more open to API integration.

Check out [DuckDuckGo's API](http://duckduckgo.com/api.html).

Comment: Quote from the website: "An API for some of our Instant Answers, not for full search results."

Answer (score 7):

Try google custom search api. Get a developer API key from google and get a cx code for search engine. The procedure is given in my blog [http://preciselyconcise.com/apis_and_installations/search_google_programmatically.php](https://web.archive.org/web/20150109103315/http://preciselyconcise.com:80/apis_and_installations/search_google_programmatically.php)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Google provides a [search API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/) that you can use:

> The Google AJAX Search API lets you
>   put Google Search in your web pages
>   with JavaScript. You can embed a
>   simple, dynamic search box and display
>   search results in your own web pages
>   or use the results in innovative,
>   programmatic ways. See the examples
>   below for inspiration.

Don't let the name fool you, this API can be used for more than just JavaScript on a webpage.

Comment: Is it okay to do this by their terms of service?

Comment: I cannot find this any more is there a replacement?

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/103123/what-ever-happened-to-the-google-ajax-search-api

Comment: Please update this answer as it is not valid anymore