# how to access Google (image) search engine data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-search, google-custom-search, google-search-api

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7172571/688869) Stackoverflow answer states that [Google's Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) allows to search the entire web.

I don't really care about the result order, but would like to...

- On my own website, using browser JavaScript or at least NodeJS, do a image search **for the whole web** using filters like [these](http://www.google.com/advanced_image_search) and process the result in JavaScript (displaying the result on my site)
- also do a reverse image search (find images similar to a specific image URL)

To be clear, I do not want to a search based on the content of my website, but instead only show the worldwide results myself.

Is that possible in a *legal* way (not by scraping the Google website)?

Note I'm only interested in public domain / CC0 images (Google is able to filter images by license).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Node.js (as the question is tagged), there is an npm module called [fotology](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fotology-x) which does what you're asking. It even allows filtering by license:

```
let options = {
    size: "large", // large images only 
    language: "fr", // French 
    safe: true, // force safe search on 
    color: "white", // white cats only please
    rights: "cc_publicdomain" // Only public domain images
}

fotology("cats", options)
.then(function (imageURLs) {
    for (i in imageURLs)
        console.log imageURLs[i];
});
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of that particular version of the module ([original module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fotology) didn't allow filtering by image license)

Comment: would be great, but: ["This API is no longer available."](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=cats)

Comment: Ah sorry, I should probably deprecate that module then.

Answer (score 0):

As this API is not available anymore, you can use our third-party service like [SerpApi](https://serpapi.com) to scrape Google and get back structured JSON.

Example using the [Node.js library](https://github.com/serpapi/google-search-results-nodejs):

```
var gsr = require('GoogleSearchResults')
let serp = new gsr.GoogleSearchResults("demo")
serp.json_with_images({
 q: "Cats Meme", 
 location: "Portland"
}, (result) => {
  console.log(result)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The only image search API that I'm aware of today (2018) is the [Bing API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-image-search/quickstarts/nodejs). I used Yahoo and Google in the past, but they both discontinued operations.

You get 1000 free searches per month, and it's about $5/1000 searches thereafter. I just implemented it last night; it works quite well.