# Script for making mulitple Google Searches at once?

Tags: google-search

I have a list of ca. 15 websites that I make a PDF search from, on a regular basis. The search word is changed from time to time. I would like to make those 15 searches in a "one click" (or at least easier) manner. Would you guys be able to help me out?

Here's my routine:

-Google Search
Oranges Filetype:pdf Site:www.siteaboutfood.com

Oranges filetype:pdf site:www.anothersiteaboutfood.com

etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to programmatically access Google's search engine results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445308/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-access-googles-search-engine-results)

Comment: you have to be more specific. StackOverflow is a programming related query portal. you have to specify the language,  to do the task and also your toy example.